# jenkins-github clone failing with no kex alg error

Tags: git, jenkins, github

We have been using jenkins and github for building the applications .From last two days jenkins is unable to fetch code from git and in console i found the error is "no kex alg" . Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error ? Any help at earliest would be highly appreciated .

> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.houston.entsvcs.net:Transportation-Seamless/tr-ace-config.git
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:817)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@github.houston.entsvcs.net:Transportation-Seamless/tr-ace-config.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:
>   stderr: no kex alg
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Have you tried to run `/usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@github.houston.entsvcs.net:Transportation-Seamless/tr-ace-config.git +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/` depending on the result your should remove all Jenkins references from this question unless it is Jenkins related.

Comment: Not just from jenkins , even when i am trying to clone a project and for ssh -t myhost name  i am getting "no kex alg" error

Comment: The next escalation step could be to check the source code of Jenkins git plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem happening to me in a situation nothing to do with Jenkins.

Basically the issue is that the Linux box which was trying to access git is so old that the crypto algorithm isn't accepted by Github any more.

The proper solution is to update the relevant packages (ie OpenSSH / OpenSSL).

I couldn't do that, so had to resort to use `rysnc` to manage files in the box until it's retired

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Did the trick for me as well.